# Word choice - nor and neither

Tags: grammar

I struggle with this one right here: which one is correct? is there another way to say it?

He does neither shelter his children from the sensitive aspects of life nor does he lie to them.

Neither does he shelter..nor does he lie to them.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Why do you think one of them is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is correct, neither and nor pair the same way as either and or. 
I would just reword it:

> He neither shelters his children from sensitive aspects of life nor does he lie to them.

Answer (score 0):

Your second alternative is correct. The first one needs to get rid of the "does": "He neither shelters his children from the sensitive aspects of life nor lies to them."